How is the impedance of SMA (or RF) connectors measured and rated?
I am going through the datasheets of 50Ω-impedance SMA terminators, trying to understand how they measure the impedance of the connector to be 50Ω and how they show this 50Ω measurement.
I would expect a Smith chart in the datasheets, showing the frequency sweep and the impedance being close to 50Ω on the Smith chart from 0Hz up to the frequency the terminator is advertised as. Instead, what I find in the datasheets is either a "50Ω impedance" description or for the "ANNE" series, I see a return loss plot:

Image from ANNE-50X+ datasheet.
This return loss plot doesn't say anything about impedance. It is a measure of how little reflections there are. Is this how the SMA terminators are measured? It shouldn't be advertised as 50Ω, but as "35db return loss" instead.

What would a professional datasheet for an SMA terminator look like? Isn't it expected to show a Smith chart up to the frequency advertised?
Is it possible that I just did not find SMA terminators that have a good datasheet? Is it the same case for all other types of RF terminators?
Using only the return loss plot to understand the quality of the RF terminator, does one assume that higher values equals closer to 50Ω impedance?


As these "resistors" are specified from DC to ~ 18 GHz, they can be measured at DC with a great precision.

If you knew the phase of the reflected signal (the extra information the smith chart would give you) how would you use it to improve your system design?


This return loss plot doesn't say anything about impedance.

This is incorrect.
The return loss is measured relative to a particular characteristic impedance. The return loss of the connector will only be high (minimal reflected wave) if the connector's characteristic impedance closely matches the system characteristic impedance.
(Or if the connector is very short relative to the operating wavelength and there are minimal parasitics --- but in this case you are not really using it as an rf connector)

Isn't it expected to show a smith chart up to the frequency advertised?

If you displayed this information on a Smith chart (for a connector with return loss better than 20 dB) all you'd see is a dot in the middle of the chart with all data points being within 0.01 of the chart center (the radius of the chart being 1.0). You wouldn't be able to distinguish a return loss of 30 dB from one of 40 dB.
In impedance terms you wouldn't be able to distinguish a connector with effective characteristic impedance of 50.1 ohms from one with 50.01 ohms.
These small differences are easily distinguished on a log-scale plot of return loss.

Using only the return loss plot to understand the quality of the RF terminator, does one assume that higher values equals closer to 50Ω impedance?

You don't have to assume anything. A higher return loss does indicate a better match between the connector characteristic impedance and the system characteristic impedance.

Thanks for the correct use of "higher" and "return loss"

As with everything, there are multiple ways of viewing data of a system, some more useful or used more often than others.
You expect a Smith chart which has the complex impedance plotted on it based on frequency. Sometimes the actual impedance or complex impedance is irrelevant and you just need to know how much RF energy gets reflected back at given frequency or range of frequencies, and this plot is what you get. Sometimes in graphical form, sometimes in tabular form.
The return loss is a measurement of the nominal 50 ohm termintor in a nominal 50 ohm environment.
No you should not expect a Smith chart. The return loss tell you how good the terminator is at some frequency or range you need.
Yes, higher return loss means less energy reflected back. 0 dB means everything reflects back, infinity means it absorbs everything and it is an ideal 50 ohm resistor.

You easily turn the 35 dB return loss into an impedance variation from 50 ohms.  Many vendors provide a return loss graph for their products.  Here's a typical return loss spec from a Pasternack terminator.

And yes greater return losses (that is, lower reflections) means the impedance is closer to 50 ohms.

Return Loss (RL) is gauged against a 50-ohm circuit impedance. One can first convert RL to a voltage standing wave ratio (VSWR) to determine the impedance from RL. For instance, an RL of 14 dB corresponds to a VSWR of 1.5. To convert VSWR to impedance, multiply by 50 Ohms or divide 50 Ohms by VSWR. Thus, with a VSWR of 1.5, the impedance would be either 1.5 x 50 = 75 Ohms or 50 / 1.5 = 33.3 Ohms
With a return loss (RL) of 30 dB and a voltage standing wave ratio (VSWR) of 1.065, the resulting impedance would be either 53.25 or 46.9 Ohms. Ironically, achieving an exact 50 Ohms is unattainable since a VSWR of 1, which would indicate a perfect match, is mathematically impossible. A RL of 60 db equals a VSWR of 1.001. Close to 50 ohms, but no cigar.

Return loss can also be applicable to a system where the impedance is not 50 ohms.

The original poster inquired specifically about SMA connectors, which have an impedance of 50 ohms.

Yes.  But I'm just questioning your wording in the first sentence, which may lead some to conclude that you need a 50 ohm load (or system) for RL to be valid.
